# Infinitely nested radicals problem about Fermat number

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, nested-radicals

**Let $F_n$ be the $n$th Fermat number $2^{2^n}+1$.Find
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{6F_1+\sqrt{6F_2+\sqrt{6F_3+\sqrt{\cdots +6F_n}}}}.$$**
This is The American Mathematical Monthly problem 11967. I think it's so difficult that I have no ideal.

Comment: Solution by Roberto Tauraso: http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~tauraso/AMM/AMM11967.pdf